# Appointment Assistant Setup - FSL

Tags: field-service-lightning, fieldservice, fsl

I'm currently attempting to complete the Field Service Settings setup.
The section on Appointment Assistance is visible along with the fields even though the package is not installed.
I don't seem to be able to save the settings without filling the Appointment Assistant fields.
Is there a way to deactivate or override the filling of those fields?

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPkwn.png)
[image]

Comment: What is the click path to appointment assistant settings that you are referring to here?  I've been able to enable field service in my org by accepting defaults (Setup>quickfind> Field Service Settings) irrespective of appointment assistant settings

Comment: I found that the license was indeed activated in the org and hence it was displaying that section of settings for Appointment Assistant. That was under Field Service Settings in Setup